# Cleaned_data doesn't pass anything

Tags: python, django, validation

I am working on a Django project and it seems like I can not use the `cleaned_data` module anywhere in my program. Every time I use it, it raises a key error (saying that key doesn't exist) and when I use `cleaned_data.get` it just passes nothing. I can use only "form.data" (as you can see in my code) and everything works fine. I just want to know why I can't use the cleaned_data?
here is my form.py:

```
class RegisterationForm(forms.Form):

    first_name = forms.CharField
    last_name = forms.CharField
    username = forms.CharField
    email = forms.EmailField
    password = forms.CharField
    password2 = forms.CharField


    def clean(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')

        if password and password != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("passwords do not match")

        return self.cleaned_data
```

here is my view.py:

def register(request):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RegisterationForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():

        user_info={}
        user_info['username'] = form.data['username']
        user_info['first_name'] = form.data['first_name']
        user_info['last_name'] = form.data['last_name']
        user_info['password'] = form.data['password']
        user_info['email']= form.data['email']

        #salt = hashlib.sha1(str(random.random())).hexdigest()[:5]
        #usernamesalt = user_info['username']
        #if isinstance(usernamesalt, unicode):
        #    usernamesalt = usernamesalt.encode('utf8')
        user_info['activation_key'] = 1#hashlib.sha1(salt+usernamesalt).hexdigest()

        form.sendEmail(user_info)
        form.save(user_info)
        return render_to_response('register_success.html',user_info)

    else:
        form_save = form

args = {}
args.update(csrf(request))
args['form'] = RegisterationForm()
return render_to_response('register.html',args)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you didn't call the parent class `clean` method to get the data first:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(RegisterationForm, self).clean()
    password = cleaned_data.get('password')
    password2 = cleaned_data.get('password2')

    if password and password != password2:
        raise forms.ValidationError("passwords do not match")
```

Check out django doc about [clean method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other).

Comment: Change your original question with the full traceback please.

Answer (score 0):

If that's really your actual code, your form doesn't have any fields because you have not called any of the field definitions. It should be:

```
class RegisterationForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField()
    last_name = forms.CharField()
    username = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.CharField()
    password2 = forms.CharField()
```